Equality between operators, on dense subspace, from a quadratic form point of view
Let $L \ge 1$ and consider a finite box $\Omega = [0,L]^{d} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$. The set of functions:
$$\psi_{p}(x) = \frac{1}{L^{d/2}}e^{i\langle p,x\rangle} \quad p\in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}$$
form a countable orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\Omega)$.
The Laplacian operator $\Delta$ is well-defined on the space of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(\Omega) \subset L^{2}(\Omega)$. Thus, on this space, we can consider the operator $f(-\Delta)$ where, for $a>0$ and $b < 0$, $f$ is given by:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{e^{a(x-b)}-1}$$
Suppose $A$ is a bounded positive (hence self-adjoint) compact operator on $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Suppose further that, for every $\varphi, \psi \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, we have the following identity:
$$\langle \varphi, A\psi\rangle = \langle \varphi, f(-\Delta)\psi\rangle \tag{1}\label{1}$$
In simple words, my question is: can we establish a connection between these two operators? Let me explain what I am trying to do. The functions $\psi_{p}$ are eigenstates of $f(-\Delta)$ and they form an ONB for $L^{2}(\Omega)$. I know that $A$ is compact, so by the Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem it has a representation:
$$A = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n}\langle \phi_{n},\cdot\rangle \phi_{n}$$
where $\lambda_{n}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\phi_{n}$ its corresponding eigenvectors.
Question 1: I wonder if I can use this representation in terms of these $\psi_{p}$ functions, since these are eigenstates of $f(-\Delta)$. In other words, by (\ref{1}), $A = f(-\Delta)$ on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. This seems to imply that the functions $\psi_{p} \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, $p \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}$, are eigenvectors of $A$. Does this mean that I can represent $A$ as:
$$A = \sum_{p\in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}}\lambda_{p}\langle \lambda_{p}\psi_{p},\cdot\rangle\psi_{p}$$
where $\lambda_{p} = f(-p)$, since $A\psi_{p} = f(-\Delta)\psi_{p} = f(-p)\psi_{p}$?
Question 2: Can we use some density argument to extend $f(-\Delta)$ to $L^{2}(\Omega)$ by means of (\ref{1}), using the fact that $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^{2}(\Omega)$? This would, in particular, imply $A = f(-\Delta)$, and the answer to Question 1 would be positive.
ADD: Okay, after some thoughts maybe the situation is simpler. Because $f$ is bounded and continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and the spectrum $\sigma(-\Delta) \subset [0,\infty)$, then $f(-\Delta)$ makes sense as a bounded linear operator on the whole $L^{2}(\Omega)$ and, by (\ref{1}), I can claim that $A = f(-\Delta)$?

What does "rapidly decreasing" mean for a function on a compact set?

@LSpice yes, just realized that. But I can replace it by $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ instead and the question remains.

I edited the post!

You actually can not use the usual functional calculus to define $f(-\Delta)$ since $-\Delta$ is not self-adjoint of $C^{\infty}$. You could do it by hand, by setting $f(-\Delta)\psi_p = f(\lambda_p)\psi_p$, with $-\Delta\psi_p=\lambda_p\psi_p$. Then, as you noted yourself at the end of your post, (1) with these vectors immediately implies that $A$ is the same operator.

@ChristianRemling I got confused. The Laplacian is supposed to be self-adjoint, no? Maybe I should be a bit more careful about the dense domain: I was using $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ not as the domain of $-\Delta$, but I was restricting the attention to the latter to (try to) avoid complications. But, the domain of $-\Delta$ should be the Sobolev space $D(-\Delta) = H^{2}(\Omega)$ for instance. Since $f$ is bounded and continuous, I should be able to define $f(-\Delta)$. Am I doing something wrong?

Yes, $-\Delta$ on $H^2$ is self-adjoint and we have the functional calculus available to define $f(-\Delta)$, but that's not what you did above, when you give $-\Delta$ the smaller domain $C^{\infty}$.

@ChristianRemling Yes, I understand now. Many thanks for pointing that out!
